# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager property or not in shared client?

Tags: afnetworking-2

I'm using `AFNetworking` for all my connections in my app. I created a singleton 'client' class that takes care of all the `AFNetworking` code and uses `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.  What I am confused about is whether the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` object should be a property, or should I recreate one everytime my client is asked for a connection? If it is a property, can my client be called many times asynchronously, or will that cause problems, since the same instance of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` will be used possibly at the same time ?

Comment: @DavidCaunt I haven't tried a property but I did try storing the manager to an instance variable and I've had bad access crashes. For some reason, the instance I've assigned to my variable died. So I think initializing a new manager upon usage (local variable) is better (it's the fix i did). By the way, I'm using ARC so an instance variable should have a strong pointer to the object assigned by default much like how a strong property works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, your singleton 'client' class would be a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.  It could also be a property, but then you won't be able to override methods.  Some commonly overridden methods are:

- `- HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:`, to modify how all request operations are constructed (for example, if you need an identical header in every request)
- `– initWithBaseURL:`, to apply additional customization to the operation manager

That said, a property could work fine depending on your needs.  (See [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1445366) for some delightful weekend reading.)

And finally:

> If it is a property, can my client be called many times asynchronously, or will that cause problems, since the same instance of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` will be used possibly at the same time?

Yes, `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is designed to be thread-safe.  You can tell it to do stuff from different threads.  (Note that its completion blocks are always called on the main thread, since UI work is typically done there.)

Comment: I choose to not subclass `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` since eventually I want to switch to `AFURLSessionManager ` when my app drops iOS6 support. Having a neutral client seems to be better for a smooth transition (but I could be mistaken). I will accept your question for answering the question regarding `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` being thread safe.

Comment: @Koen Yes, that's a good reason to use a property.  For the sake of argument, though, you could use subclassing and do the same thing with a class cluster.  (Your class could return a different subclass instance depending on the current iOS version.)